# How to Enhance Image contrast and brightness

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have a input image and i want to improve contrast and brightness

**input image:**
[image]

**After run my code result is:**
[image]

**But finally image i want(Clarity filter in Windows 10 Photos app in edit mode you can use this link for more details https://www.digitalunite.com/technology-guides/digital-photography/editing-photos-and-videos-windows-10-using-photos-app):**
[image]
(more details and better separation of objects and color)

My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.filters as filters
from PIL import ImageFilter,ImageEnhance

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('input.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (95,95),0)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=40)
# sharpen using unsharp masking
result = filters.unsharp_mask(division, radius=2.5, amount=1, multichannel=False, preserve_range=False)
result = (220*result).clip(0,220).astype(np.uint8)


cv2.imshow('smooth', result)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: does Microsoft describe how that "Clarity" filter works?

Comment: I found this definition :"Clarity is a local contrast increase that focuses on the mi-tones of the image. If differs from sharpness, because whereas increasing sharpness increases the contrast between dark and light tones, clarity increases the contrast within the middle tones of the image. The effect is similar to sharpening, but it brings out textures a bit more. In addition, digital noise isn’t as much of a problem as it is with sharpening increases"( and this link may be helped :https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/what-exactly-is-clarity/m-p/8957985).

Comment: so you accept the clarity filter from adobe, it doesn't have to be what microsoft does?

Comment: The closest explanation I could find for this filter was this, but my goal is the Microsoft Clarity filter.

Comment: “Clarity” slider will outline specific edges with darkened shadows or blend them into the background

Comment: we aren't gonna reverse-engineer some commercial closed-source "artistic filter" for which the only description is "outline specific edges with darkened shadows or blend them into the background". that's nothing to operate on. though if I may speculate, it could be "unsharp" but using DoG/bandpass instead of lowpass.

Comment: why are your pictures not all the same size and scale? did you screenshot them? do not do that. save the pictures themselves.

Comment: @md.119 Have you tried local histogram equalization?

Comment: Yes, I tested(histogram equalization) but the result was not good