# Change image clarity in Python like Microsoft photo

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to make a filter to change the clarity of the image, but no matter what I searched, I could not find any function or algorithm for this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Assuming that Microsoft uses an algorithm similar to Adobe Photoshop, there is some discussion here of how you might achieve the effect... https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/what-exactly-is-clarity/m-p/8957985

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73002013/2836621

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal, execute this command: `pip install Pillow`

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

# Read the image
img = Image.open("your-image-path-here.png")

# Image brightness enhancer
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)

factor = 1.3 # Change the value here to change the brightness
img_output = enhancer.enhance(factor)
img_output.save('my-modified-image.png') # You can name "my-modified-image" whatever you want.
```

Comment: Thank you, my friend, for answering my question, but I think clarity is different from the brightness